# How can you find a string in another string without using strpos?

Tags: php, string

I've been trying to search for a way to find a string within another string and return the position where it was found using PHP, but not using `strpos` as this will help me learn programming without relying on native functions so much.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Native functions are made for us to rely on.

Comment: But let's give it a try. What have you done so far? You said that you don't want to rely on native functions (but you are now relying on 'forums'). So you should be able to come up with code of your own. Practice logic ;)

Comment: It's not, if you could just point me in documentation, I'd be more than happy to research it myself bro?

Comment: Well I'm guessing, iterating through a for loop where $a = 'cookies' and $b  = 'coo' and then maybe checking if the value of $b's index position aka c is equal to $a's c? I'm just super confused kinda

Comment: @Steven Your guess is right. Now you can just try to code it.

Comment: I think I may have to give up on this and just rely on the functions, but I feel like If I was to learn how, it'd be easier when programming in languages which don't have native functions like php does to find the strpos. Thanks though!

Comment: As far as a documentation pointer, here is the [documentation for string access by character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

Comment: Well, don't give up just yet. Native functions are here for when you already have your way into programming (specially in a specific language). What you seem to want is to learn logic. That comes independently from language. And for that I do think that doing things 'on your own' can help. But only for that. Not really for real-deal programming. Besides, knowing those functions, how and when to use them are part of knowing how to program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with relying on native functions, but if you are just trying to figure out how something like `strpos` *could* work behind the scenes, here is a very basic example that only uses language constructs:

```
function my_strpos ($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0) {

    // for loop with indexes for both strings, up to the length of $haystack
    for ($h_index=$offset, $n_index=0; isset($haystack[$h_index]); $h_index++, $n_index++) {

        if ($haystack[$h_index] == $needle[$n_index]) {           // *CHARACTERS MATCH*

            if (!isset($start_pos)) $start_pos = $h_index;        // set start_pos if not set

            if (!isset($needle[$n_index + 1])) return $start_pos; // all characters match


        } else {                                                  // *CHARACTERS DON'T MATCH*

            $n_index = -1;                                        // reset $needle index

            unset($start_pos);                                    // unset match start pos.
        }
    }
    // all charactes of $haystack iterated without matching $needle
    return false;
}
```

This is obviously a naive implementation which doesn't check for valid input or handle errors, but hopefully it will demonstrate one possible method of finding one string within another.

If you really want to know how `strpos` *does* work behind the scenes, [here is a great (although a bit dated) article](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/16/Understanding-PHPs-internal-function-definitions.html) about how to understand the PHP source, that happens to use `strpos` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strstr, documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
<?php 
   $haystack = "Hello my dear friend";
   $needle = "friend";
// Returns false if needle is not inside haystack
   strstr($haystack, $needle);
?>
```

Comment: @TimMalone I kinda hope you are being sarcastic. It was probably done without reading the question (that talks about native functions). Besides, this code doesn't even 'find' the position of a string inside another: [https://eval.in/604353](https://eval.in/604353) - no position returned...